# Android request a url with out opening browser

Tags: java, android

So I have an arduino with an Ethernet shield and I am currently controlling it using browser url commands eg "192.168.2.1/digital/2/1" (digital pin 2 goes high), i want to have an android button which requests that url without opening it in the browser.. is that possible and how would i do it?

Comment: See "WiktionarySimple" in the samples/ directory of the SDK

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I do URL requests in Android:

```
public InputStream download(String url) {
    URL myFileURL = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        myFileURL = new URL(url);
        is = myFileURL.openStream();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return is;
}
```

This will return whatever is at that URL and it will never open a browser.  You can choose whatever you want to do with the InputStream.

Comment: If this is the first use of networking within the application itself, Internet permission must be added to the manifest, too.  (Only mentioned to avoid that causing another question if David didn't already know this)

Comment: Yes this is very true.  Thank you for mentioning this Chris.  David just add this line to the manifest file. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />